# no audio after mp3 + jpg with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mp3 file. I checked. It has audio. After run command

```
ffmpeg -i 31.mp3 -i cover.jpg -c:a copy -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p 31.mp4
```

I got 31.mp4 but it has no audio.

I use macbook pro and ffmpeg version 4.1

Answer (score 1):

It's not ffmpeg issue. It's quicktime player issue. Change "-c:a copy" to "-c:a aac" fixed the issue.